# ExtJS :: Store loadData method optimization

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have some data in array (23000 records). I need to load it into store. I test performance in virtual machine.

Chrome do loading for 4 seconds, IE8 for 200! seconds. I've suspended events on this store. What can I do to optimize this part of application. (IE drops annoying errors about long running script)..

```
Wtb.getPlanShiftStore().suspendEvents(false);   
Wtb.getPlanShiftStore().loadData(data);    
Wtb.getPlanShiftStore().resumeEvents();
```

Maybe there is some another method, that will do it faster, or I need to override something? I just need to create models and put it into store's data... Or it's impossible...?

Comment: And you're recording time right before `loadData` and right after? How is your data defined?

Comment: I'm using (new Date()).getTime(), and then count difference before and after. data is defined like big array, with simple objects (that will be converted to models by loadData method).

Comment: Have you tried to define a store with this data already in?

Comment: I have Ext-MVC application. Stores being loaded at start of application, and then data is generating...

Comment: I understand. I use same approach too. However for static data I create special kind of stores - I put them inside store\static directory. And I define them as totally local and with data already in them. I don't think it violates MVC paradigm - and I was just wondering if you define them this way - how it will change speed.

Comment: Why would you need to load that many records?

Comment: My application logic need that amount of data.

Comment: When I define Store with data already in, time of create is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[loadRecords](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Store.html#Ext-data-Store-method-loadRecords) do `suspendEvents` itself. Try [sortOnLoad](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-property-sortOnLoad) : `false`, maybe it will help a little.
And use server-side data pagination.

Comment: I though OP was talking about loading static data not from the remote store.

Comment: I'm geberating all this data on client. IE generate array for 10 seconds, and load it for 200 seconds... Sort is off.

Comment: I understand but I ask (as @Neil McGuigan above): “why”?